# Sorting on date gives me error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've an issue while sorting date by arrow sorting. I successfully implemented this for "Subject" and "Status" field on Task object but while i click on Date column , it gives me error saying : unexpected token:  Error is in expression '{!toggleSort}' in page new_test_task_assignment: Class.PagingTasksController1.toggleSort: line 61, column 1 .Why can be this issue ? Please help . Thanks in advance.

```
   public void toggleSort() {
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

    integer iIndex = sApplySOQL.indexOf('Order By');
    if (iIndex > -1){
        sApplySOQL = sApplySOQL.substringBefore('Order By');
        sApplySOQL = sApplySOQL + ' Order By ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir +  ' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;
      }
     System.debug('Sorted Date is ' +sApplySOQL);
     Tasks = Database.query(sApplySOQL );
  }


   <apex:column headerValue="Due Date">
      <apex:facet name="header">
          <apex:commandLink value="ActivityDate" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgTable" >
            <apex:param name="sortField" value="ActivityDate" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
           <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!BEGINS(sortField,'ActivityDate')}">
                      &nbsp;<apex:image value="{!IF(sortDir = 'desc','/img/arrowDown.gif','/img/arrowUp.gif')}"/>
           </apex:outputPanel>
         </apex:commandLink>
      </apex:facet>     
     <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.ActivityDate}"/>
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: If line 61 is the Database.query call then review the debug output of sApplySOQL for the cause of the problem.

Comment: Kieth , i did Debug on my Console , there is not showing me anything with my debugging. Do you see any thing unrelated with this when it comes to date sorting ?

Comment: I don't see anything. Use the line number information information that you get and add more debugging output until you narrow down the problem.

Comment: `unexpected token` is likely to be an error in the dynamically constructed SOQL that you use for the date field. Using the system.debug output, paste that into the SOQL execute pane in Developer Console or Eclipse IDE to see what is in error. Often, it is just a missing space.